# ReactiveSearch (ReactJS) w/ Elasticsearch CORS error

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, cors, reactivesearch

I am trying to connect my front-end React app with a local elasticsearch node. I am using [ReactiveSearch](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/getting-started/reactivesearch.html) to connect elasticsearch. My server is running on Digital Ocean and it's running Ubuntu 16.04. I followed their [quickstart guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-16-04) to get elasticsearch running on the server and have added the following lines to my elasticsearch.yml file:

`http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.allow-methods: OPTIONS,HEAD,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers: X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type,Content-Length`

My ReactJS component looks exactly like the ReactiveSearch getting started says it should look:

```
            <ReactiveBase
                app="users"
                url="http://localhost:9200">
                <DataSearch
                    componentId="SearchSensor"
                    dataField={["email", "username", "name"]}
                    title="Search"
                    placeholder="Search for users..."
                />
            </ReactiveBase>
```

But, I am getting CORS errors for the preflight request headers:

[image]

When I try to visit the url: `http://localhost:9200/users/active/_msearch`, I get this response:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"},"status":400}
```

But, if I go to the url: `http://localhost:9200/users/active/1` it actually works and brings up that object:

`{"_index":"users","_type":"active","_id":"1","_version":1,"found":true,"_source":{ "name": "Jon Stevens", "email": "jon@vendorpay.io" }}`

What in the world is going on here?? Any help is greatly appreciated!

SCREENSHOT OF REQUEST/CONSOLE:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens when you leave out the type on the msearch request URL?

Comment: Same result: `{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"},"status":400}`

Comment: That is usually from badly formatted request. For msearch endpoint the content-type header should be set to application/x-ndjson. Have you tried using postman or curl?

Comment: Both postman and curl give me the same result. Also, changing the headers would mean modifying the package in `node_modules`.

Comment: In postman I tried changin the `content-type` header to `application/x-ndjson` and still the same result.

Comment: @JonStevens One of the contributors to ReactiveSearch here - I suspect the error you see is caused due to a malformed request. Can you paste the full network request that is being made in your question (Headers, Request Body)?

Comment: Is it possible to get that error if I'm including `username` in the data fields I'm searching on but it doesn't exist on the objects of that index?

Comment: Nope, that wasn't it. I've updated the question to include a screenshot of the request and console.

Comment: @JonStevens - did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same error and setup

Comment: I never did. I ended up just implementing the hosted elasticsearch appbase.io until  I figure it out.